# How to upload file from windows using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, file, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload file using selenium WebDriver,

There is one popwindow which is having 'Browse' button, after click on 'Browse' it opens file from windows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHYES.png

```
{
      //Switch focus on pop window
      String popupHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
      WebDriver popup;
      popup = driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);

      //Click on 'Browse Files' button.
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      WebElement filebrowse = driver.findElement(By.id("browse-files"));
      filebrowse.sendKeys("C:/Users/logo.jpg");
 }
```

I want to upload single as well as multiple files,Is there any other way to select multiple file from window?

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/selenium-unable-to-automate-file-upload/11781#11781 have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

filebrowse.sendKeys("file://C:/Users/logo.jpg");

You need to provide absolute path.

I checked it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine. I am assuming that your locator is able to identify the button and please check first to close your pop-up that windows controller is shifted to pop-up properly

Now the thing is windows and linux/mac is consider slashes `/` differnently

If you are working on windows then use forward `\` and for unix/mac use back `/`

Example:-

For windows use below syntax

```
filebrowse.sendKeys("C:\Users\logo.jpg");
```

Try also with

```
filebrowse.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\logo.jpg");
```

For mac/linux use below syntax

```
filebrowse.sendKeys("C:/Users/logo.jpg");
```

OR

```
filebrowse.sendKeys("C://Users//logo.jpg");
```

If still not work then it is good to post your HTML code so we can check your locator as well

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: from his code what i understood is "when he click on brows file button it open windows dialogue to select the file to upload", he is clicking on button not on text box to pass the path of a file

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/selenium-unable-to-automate-file-upload/11781#11781 go and have a look at it

Comment: I am not saying that Auto-It and sikuli can't upload files while I am saying you can upload file using selenium-webdriver too using senkeys so why to use those platform dependent tools which take your automation dependent on windows only(AUTO-IT)... http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test

Comment: Code works fine, Only problem is how to select file from windows.

Comment: Yes we can upload file with Sendkeys and I have done same in my other projects but I am asking about other option apart from Sendkeys.

Comment: It is not about click on upload button, First I need to select file from windows.

Comment: Are you sure that your controller is shifted to pop-up properly.. Try to close that pop-up .. if the pop-up closed that means controllers are shifted fine .. Selenium is not providing any other way .. you can use Robot classes but they are not recommanded

Answer (score -2):

Handling windows dialogues is not supported by selenium webdriver,
for that there are third party tools available Like **Sikuli and AutoIt**
for you(By looking at your image) have two choices

1. Upload using textbox
2. Using windows dialogues(for this you need to use tools like : AutoIt,Sikuli)

for text box first you need to check is that enabled to type any text, then pass the path of the file.

```
Driver.findElement(by.id("")).sendKeys("path of file");
```

Comment: Uploading files is supported by Selenium WebDriver.